# determine the current size of a FlexTable in GWT

Tags: gwt, dialog, flextable

I need to know the current size of a `FlexTable` in order to resize a `DialogBox` accordingly (`FlexTable` lives inside the `DialogBox`).
I did not find a way to do that automatically, but I would at least want to be able to do it manually be determining the height and the width of the `FlexTable` and then resize the `DialogBox` accordingly.
Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call `getOffsetHeight()` and `getOffsetWidth()` methods on corresponding `FlexTable`.

Comment: I think I found it out just now.

Comment: I agree that it is not intuitive. Why they called these methods in a such a way? `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` are ten times faster to find for the first time.

Comment: The methods are most likely declared that way because basic DOM elements contain another height method: [getClientHeight](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Element.html#getClientHeight()).  `getOffsetHeight` includes decoration whereas `getClientHeight` does not.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found it out just now.
Its the following method of the FlexTable class:

```
FlexTable ft = new FlexTable(); 
... 
int width = ft.getElement().getStyle().getWidth(); 
int height = ft.getElement().getStyle().getHeight();
```

But that still does not work with my DialogBox issue. It's still not resized.
I'll ask that in a separate question.